# Connecting RabbitMq to an TCP/IP server

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMq as a Queueing Mechanism for my message handling.
So far, all the queues are generating fine on the localhost but when I moved on to the server. It started showing

```
    connection timeout error
```

This is my connecion string.

```
    var amqp = require('amqp');
    var connection = amqp.createConnection({
        url: 'amqp://username:passwprd@server-IP:5672/'
      })
    connection.on('error',(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      });
    var options = { autoDelete:false,
            durable:false,
            expiration:'20000',
     };
    connection.on('ready',()=>{
        connection.queue('queueName',options,(queue)=>{
            queue.bind('#');
            queue.subscribe({ack:true},message =>{
                console.log(message);
           });
       });
      });
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: add more information to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html  This is the url I have used to come up with that connection string

Comment: You should add what you have tried for connect to server completely, not just a line of it. please consider to [how ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Is the firewall allowing connections to that port?

Comment: Yes, I am giving the access

Comment: It's pretty clear that your application can't connect to RabbitMQ. Our team has a comprehensive set of diagnostic steps here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html. Also, remember that the `guest` user can only connect via `localhost` by default. However, I don't believe that is the error you are getting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I get what you are asking

Just type this code

```
     var connection = amqp.createConnection({
    url: 'amqp://localhost'
  })
```

on your server side code and the project will run fine as it is running on my server.

You don't need to specify the username and password or your server-ip.

Answer (score 1):

I have launched the Ubuntu EC2 instance and using putty utility I have installed rabbitq on the same.
To know the status of rabbitmq service, you can type **service rabbitmq-server status**
[image]
You can refer documentation from Rabbitmq [node Rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html)
I have tried with below code on aws instance and its working

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
    console.log(conn);
});
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Yes on my local environment my project is running fine. But when I try to make queues on my AWS server it shows timeout error

Comment: @DeepanshuSukhija I have updated my answer. Tried with aws ec2 ubuntu instance and its working